# How Do I Extract This List Using XPath?

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, extract, text-extraction

I’m trying get the list of texts from the filter area.  What is the XPath I should use? Sorry, I’m not good at XPath.

Thanks in advance for any help.

*edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use classname as xpath to retrieve texts.

```
(//div[@class="fe"])[1]
```

Comment: Thank you Yun, I really appreciate your reply. Here's the thing: I'm trying to extract the text using Google Sheets' `importxml` function. When I tried to use the xpath you provided it says `#N/A imported content is empty`. Why do you think this might happen? I would be glad if you could check it through this link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CGxg8Z5pYIeCf_w3XFrET5ksEUa5OZAuzpWyiKjp8yY